# mysql explain result just have DATA_NODE and SQL

Tags: mysql, explain, php-opencloud

after executing explain in mysql client, the result is:

```
mysql> explain select * from tbl_demo;
+-----------+------------------------+
| DATA_NODE | SQL                    |
+-----------+------------------------+
| dn1       | select * from tbl_demo |
+-----------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

can't find id, select_type, table, key, ref, rows and Extra column why?

Comment: Please provide the model of your database

Comment: `mysql> SELECT @@VERSION;` `mysql> SELECT @@VERSION_COMMENT;`

Comment: 5.6.27-log         MyCat Server (OpenCloundDB)